# Windows 11 Snipping Tool: Screenshot copied to clipboard, but couldn't save

Tags: windows, windows-11-v22h2, snipping-tool

This has been happening on my Windows 11 ever since I installed [KB5027231](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/june-13-2023-kb5027231-os-build-22621-1848-8f903600-1293-4431-9c6b-736a4049666c) (OS Build 22621.1848). Every time I use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to make a screenshot, Windows Snipping Tool fails with this (super informative) error message:

> Screenshot copied to clipboard, but couldn't save.

Then I can't edit/highlight anything. I have to resort to <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> + Paint app. There are many 3rd party replacements for Snipping Tool out there, but I'd like to stick with the standard one.

There are a few similar reports about this issue on the web, but I couldn't find an ultimate fix. I hope someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an user friendly answer,

1. Install the FOSS [BC crap uninstaller](https://github.com/Klocman/Bulk-Crap-Uninstaller/releases/) and run as administrator.
2. Right click on Snipping Tool.
3. Select uninstall manually and click on deleted selected.
4. Uninstall and reinstall snipping tool from Microsoft store. (optional)

Answer (score 0):

As a note to future self, here's how I fixed this annoying issue:

1. In Admin Terminal:

   ```
   winget uninstall "Snipping Tool"
   takeown "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" 
   cd "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" 
   cmd /c for /d %f in ("Microsoft.ScreenSketch*.*") do rd %f /s
   cd "%LocalAppData%\Packages"
   cmd /c for /d %f in ("Microsoft.ScreenSketch*.*") do rd %f /s
   winget install "Snipping Tool"
   ```

   This uninstalls, cleans up, and reinstalls "Snipping Tool".

   If that has worked for you, great, we're done! For me though, the last command failed with error `0x80246007`. I could no more install "Snipping Tool" from either `winget` or Windows Store. Comes part two:
2. Go to https://store.rg-adguard.net, paste `https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/snipping-tool/9MZ95KL8MR0L` into their app URL entry box.
3. Find the latest "Snipping Tool" version MSIX in the generated list. In my case, it was `Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2305.25.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle`.
4. Verify the URL is coming from `*.microsoft.com`, right-click on it, do "Save Link As", rename the downloaded file to `.MSIX` and run it. That should fix the broken installation.
5. Now you can do `winget uninstall` / `winget install` again, it should work (it did for me).
6. The app works OK now. Bingo, no need to reset Windows!